# Power Query table result with Dynamic name on sink

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, powerquery

In my **Azure Data Factory** pipeline have a task in **power query**, that once finished as a sink destination has a file in **azure blob storage**, how can I dynamically save the name of that file? the option to add dynamically is not enabled.

[My actually task](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QG9ytdNYtc5kI8pXQ35VT5cEmkS7wZ2s/view?usp=sharing)

[This is that I'm looking for](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v9oMPtMnRcyN1Uo0wKCrNilWnVdtv_3x/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To give your filename any dynamic name, you need to create a `Parameter` and give that parameter a value (name) which will be used in your pipeline. You can also use any expression in the value for any parameter.

[image]

Refer: https://gbamezai.medium.com/azure-data-factory-capture-dynamic-filenames-in-mapping-data-flow-6b58cd6654f8